# Significant-Change Location Service vs. Standard Location Service in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager, region-monitoring

I have an app which supports background monitoring. For my app to be able to register background movement of device I must call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`. However, at some point in my code I must also call `startUpdatingLocation()`.

My question is, if I call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` and later in my code I call `startUpdatingLocation()`, will significant monitoring be overridden? Specifically, if I terminate my app will my location manager still receive updates on significant location changes?

Comment: I would expect that significant location change notification changes would persist even if you activate "live" location updates and then terminate your app, but you're going to have to test it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

After a few testings I’ve come to a conclusion that even if “live” location updates are activated, significant location changes notifications will still be received while running app in background or when terminated. Hope others will find this useful.